# Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state

Tags: apache-flink

When I config to use `RocksDBStatebackend`,

```
RocksDBStateBackend rocksDBStateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend("hdfs://xxxx");
streamEnv.setStateBackend(rocksDBStateBackend);
```

there are some exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: java.io.IOException: Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state. Size=153682140 , maxSize=5242880 . Consider using a different state backend, like the File System State backend.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:636)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(AsyncCheckpointRunnable.java:128)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state. Size=153682140 , maxSize=5242880 . Consider using a different state backend, like the File System State backend.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory.checkSize(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory$MemoryCheckpointOutputStream.closeAndGetBytes(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemCheckpointStreamFactory$MemoryCheckpointOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(MemCheckpointStreamFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.CheckpointStreamWithResultProvider$PrimaryStreamOnly.closeAndFinalizeCheckpointStreamResult(CheckpointStreamWithResultProvider.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.FullSnapshotAsyncWriter.get(FullSnapshotAsyncWriter.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SnapshotStrategyRunner$1.callInternal(SnapshotStrategyRunner.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SnapshotStrategyRunner$1.callInternal(SnapshotStrategyRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AsyncSnapshotCallable.call(AsyncSnapshotCallable.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:633)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Seems like the RocksdbStatebackend will use FsStateBackend to store checkpoints. So it means that I have used FileSystemStateBackend, why does this exception occur?

I use flink 1.13.0 and found a similar question like this at: [Flink state backend config with the state processor api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314652/flink-state-backend-config-with-the-state-processor-api)

I'm not sure if his question is same with mine.

I want to know how can I solve this and if it is indeed a 1.13.0 bug, how can I bypass it besides upgrading?

Comment: The APIs involved changed in Flink 1.13. The issue is that you haven't configured your checkpoint storage, so you are getting the default (which is to store checkpoints on the job manager heap). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67832673/2000823 for details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think this is a BUG for flink. There has more info in my issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24314. Seems like the tableEnv's config effect streamEnv's config.